# react, wepack, babel, node, npm start error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

#### ERROR in ./main.js

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>
> Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-es2015' from 'F:\reactapp'
>     at Function.module.exports [as sync] (F:\reactapp\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:43:15)
>     at resolveStandardizedName (F:\reactapp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:101:31)
>    at resolvePreset (F:\reactapp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:58:10)
>     at loadPreset (F:\reactapp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:77:20)
>     at createDescriptor (F:\reactapp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
>     at items.map (F:\reactapp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50)
>     at Array.map ()
>       at createDescriptors (F:\reactapp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
>     at createPresetDescriptors (F:\reactapp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
>     at passPerPreset (F:\reactapp\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:58:96)
>   @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./main.js main[2]
>
> Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
>      1 asset
>     Entrypoint undefined = index.html
>     [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html] 448 bytes {0} [built]
>     [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0} [built]
>     [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built] 
>     [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
>
> i ?wdm?: Failed to compile.
>
> Terminate batch job (Y/N)?

#### package.json file:

package json file is as follows. I followed https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "demo project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "[]"
  ],
  "author": "manjunathan g",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.28.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

#### babel config:

Babel config file is as below; followed as per https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

```
{
  "presets":["env", "react"]
}
```

#### webpack config

webpack config is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/bundle'),
      filename: 'index_bundle.js'
   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/es2015'],
               plugins: ['@babel/proposal-class-properties']
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   plugins:[
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         template: './index.html'
      })
   ]
}
```

Comment: someone pls help me, im struggling to start my first project.

Comment: I have reformatted your question a bit. But you should still add some description of what you are trying to do and more importantly: A good question consists not only of a dump of an error message and source files, but of a well formulated ... question.

Answer (score 2):

The [`@babel/preset-es2015`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-es2015) package has been deprecated and you can no longer install it from NPM.

The recommendation now is to use [`@babel/preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes in your file configuration. Let me try to solve it:

#### *.babelrc*

You don't need the following devDependencies: *babel-core*, *babel-preset-env*, *babel-preset-react* and *babel-preset-es2015*. They are deprecated since *Babel 7* was realeased. Substitute your code to this:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

#### *webpack.config.js*

Since *webpack 4* was released, you don't need to inform the entry and output fields (You can do it for custom configurations). By default, *webpack* will look for `index.js` file located in the `src/` directory (this directory must be in the root of your project). *Webpack* will create the module dependency graph from this file and output the bundled file to the `dist/` directory. Try to configure your *webpack.config.js* like this:

```
const path = require("path")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: { loader: "babel-loader" }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: { loader: "html-loader" } //Install it: 'npm i -D html-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
         new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
              template: "src/index.html" // Put the index.html in the src/ directory
         })
    ]
}
```

I'm not an expert in configuring webpack and I don't know if I could help you. I wrote an article on medium setting the environment to work with react, babel and webpack, but it is in **portuguese**. If you want to check: https://medium.com/@brunonakayabu/react-webpack-e-babel-configurando-o-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-c7ee8a994222